# Foreach kotlin loop always read the same element

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing an App in Kotlin, where I try to use KMM architecture, where I recover some data from a remote API, and try to keep into localdatabase.

The libraries which I'm using are Ktor and SQLDelight, for remote and local connections.

My problem comes after recover the remote data, and try to map the array of elements in order to insert into localdatabase. I see debuging that the index of the foreach loop always remains in 0, so when try to insert the same element the app crash.

The rest of the code works fine, and even the API call recover the data correctly.

The code is the following:

```
  private fun cacheMembers(pets: List<UnsplashPhoto>) {
    queries.deleteAll()
    pets.forEachIndexed { i , pet ->
      queries.insertPet(
          pet.id?.toLong()!!,
          pet.description!!,
          pet.urls.regular,
          pet.user.username
      ).also {
        Log.d("info", "Inserta el pet $i con id: ${pet.id}")
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Retorna un Flow con una lista de Pets, y guardando en la BD local
   * los pets recuperados de la llamada de red.
   */
  private fun getFromRemote(): Flow<List<UnsplashPhoto>?> {
    println("Getting members from remote")
    return flow {
      val unsplashPhotos = api.getPets()?.results
      Log.d("info",  "size pets llamada de red: ${unsplashPhotos!!.size}")
      Log.d("info", "pets $unsplashPhotos")
      cacheMembers(unsplashPhotos!!).also {
        Log.d("info", "Inserta los pets en local")
      }
      emit(unsplashPhotos).also {
        Log.d("info", "Emite el Flow de Pets")
      }
    }
        .catch { error(RefreshDataException()) }
        .flowOn(applicationDispatcher)
  }
```

I added a picture showing the index remain in 0, after the insert of the firts element

[image]

I don't know quite well how manage this, due to I try other approach like while loop which an iterator, and a regular for loop, but the problem remain the same.

If you experience this, and can help, take thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

Added the logcat

verbose:

```
STACKTRACE: [com.jshvarts.kmp.repository.PetsRepository$getFromRemote$2.invokeSuspend(PetsRepository.kt:70), com.jshvarts.kmp.repository.PetsRepository$getFromRemote$2.invoke(Unknown Source:14), kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catch$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:114), kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catch$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12), kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(PipelineContext.kt:238), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:194), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:67), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(PipelineContext.kt:144), kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(PipelineContext.kt:238), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:194), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:67), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(PipelineContext.kt:144), kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(PipelineContext.kt:238), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:194), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:67), io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(PipelineContext.kt:144), kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46), kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56), kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571), kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738), kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678), kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)] + com.jshvarts.kmp.api.RefreshDataException
```

error:

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xiaomi.discover-AgvtR7TVxyrOt_nJ_Vc-eQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xiaomi.discover-AgvtR7TVxyrOt_nJ_Vc-eQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xiaomi.discover-AgvtR7TVxyrOt_nJ_Vc-eQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:228)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:733)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:812)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1034)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2357)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5867)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1679)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2021-12-29 14:38:25.160 30072-30072/? E/DeviceLevel: MiDeviceLevelBridge(): Load Class Exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.miui.performance.DeviceLevelUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/MiuiBooster.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64]]
```

[EDIT]

After some app debugging, I can see that the problem is in the localDatabase of the App , where crash after try to insert the pets which recover from the network, into the localdatabase.

The probem is when I try to read the array which contains the pets, using a foreach loop, always iterates the firts element, and crash.

Any idea why is doing this?

here is the code where fails:

PetsRepository.kt

```
....

  fun fetchAsFlow(force: Boolean): Flow<List<UnsplashPhoto>?> {
    return if (force) getFromRemote() else getFromCache()
  }
  /**
   * Fail due to when read the array of pets, create from Network call, only read the firts elements, and try to add always the same.
   * index always remain the same.
   */
  private fun cacheMembers(pets: List<UnsplashPhoto>) {
    queries.deleteAll()
    pets.forEachIndexed  {i, pet ->
      queries.insertPet(
          pet.id!!,
          pet.description!!,
          pet.urls.regular,
          pet.user.username
      ).also {
        Log.d("info", "Inserta el pet $i con id: ${pet.id}")
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Retorna un Flow con una lista de Pets, y guardando en la BD local
   * los pets recuperados de la llamada de red.
   */
  private fun getFromRemote(): Flow<List<UnsplashPhoto>?> {
    println("Getting members from remote")
    return flow {
      val unsplashPhotos = api.getPets()?.results
      Log.d("info",  "size pets llamada de red: ${unsplashPhotos!!.size}")
      Log.d("info", "pets $unsplashPhotos")
      cacheMembers(unsplashPhotos!!).also {
        Log.d("info", "Inserta los pets en local")
      }
      emit(unsplashPhotos).also {
        Log.d("info", "Emite el Flow de Pets")
      }
    }
        .catch { error(RefreshDataException()) }
        .flowOn(applicationDispatcher)
  }
....
```

I also added a picture showing the log, where I analyze the content of the response.

Comment: You’re not using `i`. You’re using `pet.id`.

Comment: And how should I change in code? Thanks for your comment

Comment: Can you post the crash log??

Comment: I already edit added the error and verbose logs.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `System.nanoTime()` instead of regular id. Because it can be duplicate of other primary key.

Comment: What happens when your app restarts?

Comment: Do the same, and the screen stay in white